# Selecting the parent of a parent to find an uncle

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have this code working fine with FF and opera but not with safari and chrome.

```
j(this).parent().parent().find(".box").load('test.html');
```

where (this) is for example the "a" in the following example html

```
<div>
   <p><a href="#">clicky</a> to do ajax<p>
   <div class="box">loadhere</div>
</div>
```

if i do parent only once I'm at the p tag, this prevents me from finding the "box", so i do parent twice to get to the div. how can i get to the div in all browsers?

Comment: How do you know it is not an Aunt?

Comment: @Darmen: no i'm using safemode

Comment: @Josh Stodola: probably right, when searching for a box ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.box');
```

Comment: that's how you find an uncle ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('div')
```

if you want to be more sure you're getting the right one, give the div a class or something.

```
$(this).closest('div.magicAjaxContainer')
```

Comment: will this select box or the grandparent?

Comment: It selects the first parent (working upwards) that matches the given selector. Note that it's kind-of fragile to rely on a very specific DOM structure anyway. You might need to change your HTML because of style or layout issues.

Comment: This does not work in the OPs example as `<div class="boy">` is not an ancestor of `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$(this).parent().next('div.box')
```